# UK Visit Visa - Bank Statement Explanation

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

So I'm a US permanent resident applying for a 6-months visit visa. For bank statements, should i be able to explain every single out-of-ordinary expenditure/withdrawal from my savings account?

Specifically, for this month, I've already made several big refundable payments (hotels and flights) towards my UK trip and they all reflect as credit card payment withdrawals from my savings account. Should I supply my receipts for those even though UKVI does not recommend submitting receipts for hotels and flights?

Or should I just submit my bank statements without explaining any big withdrawal? Will the visa officer literally do the math themselves to check my normal monthly expenditure? I'm afraid these withdrawals will reflect my erratic lifestyle if I dont give exlanations.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not repeat asking the same question. The first time you asked you got an answer that should work for you. But this and the previous questions are duplicates of the question which is mentioned in the close message. If you do not agree with the closere you can edit your first question and if your arguments are strong enough that question may be reopened. Any further questions on the same lines will also be closed as duplicates.

Comment: One of the reasons we do not give you more instructions what to do is that we do not have all details nor do we know what the immigration officers get for instructions.